# MIPS – 5 bits to represent registers?

Tags: mips, computer-science, cpu-architecture, machine-code

In MIPS, the opcodes for registers is 5 bits long.

I read that each register is 32 bits long, so why are only 5 used to represent their opcodes in the instruction format?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.cs.uwm.edu/classes/cs315/Bacon/Lecture/HTML/ch05s03.html

"For example, the MIPS processor has 32 general-purpose registers, so it takes 5 bits to specify which one to use. In contrast, the MIPS has a 4 gibibyte memory capacity, so it takes 32 bits to specify which memory cell to use. An instruction with 3 operands will require 15 bits if they are all registers, and 96 bits if they are all memory addresses."

Compute all things in base 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can address up to 4GiB of RAM with only 32 bits, right? This is because `2^32` gives you `4'294'967'296`, which is the amount of independent "cells" you can access. Each of those "cells" are 8 bits (a byte).

The same thing happens with registers, except that each "cell" is 32 bits rather than 8 bits. With 5 bits for addressing registers, you get `2^5 = 32` possible cells - i.e. 32 possible registers of 32 bits.

The capacity of a register is not related to the quantity of bits you need to address a certain amount of registers.